# Constructor or function to change class fields

Tags: java, oop, class, constructor

I have with two fields: long nr and a vector of long like below:

```
public class Pair {

    public long nr;
    public Vector<Long> lines;

    public Pair(long ap, long line){
        this.nr=ap;
        if (line!=0) lines.add(linie);
         else lines=null; 
    }

    public void create (long line){
        nr++;
        lines.add(line);
    }
}
```

I want to have a function(create) so it modifies the fields of the class. In the main class I have

```
Pair per1=new Pair(0,0);
Pair per2=new Pair(0,0);

per1.create(3);
per2.create(4);
```

The constructor works fine, but create doesn't. What is the explanation, and how should the function look like?Thanks a lot.

Comment: According to the code, `lines` is null when you call `create()`. Your code should throw a `NullPointerException`. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never created instance of Vector by calling `new Vector<Long>()` in your code. Moreover you are setting your class variable `lines` to `null` if `line == 0`.

Your code should like this:

```
public class Pair {

public long nr;
public Vector<Long> lines = new Vector<long>();

public  Pair(long ap, long line){
    this.nr=ap;
    if (line!=0) lines.add(linie);
}

public void create (long line){
    nr++;
    if (line!=0) lines.add(linie);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

- Your constructor will never work for non-zero values; it will throw a null pointer exception. This is because you never initialize `lines`. You will need to initialize it either when you define it as a member or in the constructor (as `lines = new Vector<Long>();`)
- You will always get a null pointer exception because you set the variable `lines` to `null` when you call your constructor with the `line` argument as `0`. When you subsequently call `create`, you will get a null pointer exception when `lines.add(line)` is run.

To fix your problems I would do something like this:

```
lines = new Vector<Long>();

if(line != 0) {
   lines.add(line);
}
```

Notice there's no `else`. I'm not sure why you need to set `lines` to `null`, but realize that if you do, you won't be able to use it later. It's also a pretty weird side-effect that is bound to cause confusion to the users of your class.

A few other pointers.

- Please use proper Java syntax and naming conventions. Always surround your `if`'s and `else`'s with braces:

  if(line != 0) {
     lines.add(line);
  } else {
     ...
  }

  - Use descriptive variable names. `nr` and `ap` aren't very clear.
  - Do `nr` and `lines` really need to be `public`? That is the exception rather than the rule.

Comment: Constructor is working because he never calls it with anything but 0.

Answer (score 1):

The line in the constructor sets your Vector to null, so you cant add to it later.

```
if (line!=0) lines.add(linie);
        else lines=null; // <-- cant call add later on lines
```

Btw it wouldnt even work if you call your constructor with any other parameter, since you never initialize your lines Vector at all.

I dont know what you exactly try to do but you can change your field definition to

```
public Vector<Long> lines = new Vector<Long>();
```

And then remove the else in your contructor.

Answer (score 1):

Your `lines` vector is never initialised. Calling your constructor with a value other than `0` is also going to throw a NullPointerException.

You can either change the field declaration to `Vector<Long> lines = new Vector<Long>();` or call `lines = new Vector<Long>();` at the beginning of your constructor, and simply do nothing if the value of the second argument is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm not sure the name of class matches the behavior. Names like `nr` make working with code very difficult. Consider renaming that to something more meaningful.

The key is that you never create a Vector object, only references.

so I would make your constructor do this:

```
public  Pair(long ap, long line){
    this.nr=ap;
    lines = new Vector<Long>();
    if (line!=0) lines.add(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for lines is missing.

Either in the definition of lines or in the constructor of Pair you have to initialise lines:

```
lines = new Vector<Long>();
```